# IIS virtual directory creation fails on IIS 7.0 / windows server 2008

Tags: nant, nantcontrib

When I tried to create a virtual directory in the remote server using `NAnt` build script It could not create and shows the error message below:

```
The webservice at 'remote_machine' does not exist or is not reachable
```

The OS of remote server is **Windows server 2008**. Here I have used `NAnt 0.92` and `natcontrib 0.92`.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

EDiT: It is working for local machine but not for the remote. Any suggestion Please.

the code portion:

```
<property name="serverName" value="MyServer"/>
<property name="currentDeployName" value="Research"/>      
<property name="deployDir" value="\\${serverName}\wwwroot\${currentDeployName}"/>
<property name="currentDir" value="${deployDir}"/>  
<property name="DeployWebDir" value="${sourceDir}\Deployment\Deployment.Web"/>  
<property name="webrootDir" value="C:\Inetpub\wwwroot"/> 


<deliisdir iisserver="${serverName}" vdirname="${currentDeployName}" />        
<mkdir dir="${deployDir}" />     
<copy todir="${deployDir}" overwrite="true">
  <fileset basedir="${DeployWebDir}">
    <include name="**\*" />
  </fileset>
</copy>   
<mkiisdir iisserver="${serverName}" dirpath="${webrootDir}\${currentDeployName}"
           vdirname="${currentDeployName}"/>
```

Comment: Can you post your script here?

Comment: Hi Arpit, I have posted the code portion. Please have a look on that.

Comment: I believe you are passing the remote server's hostname in `serverName` property? Also, have you tried pinging the remote server, if it is reachable or not?

Comment: yes.Okay ...I have tried to run the build script from command line. and it is successfully working.Bear in mind that i have opened the command line as admin mode. So i suspect it is for security issue. Another thing is that I have created a user and add it to the administrator group and then use the same user for the agent. But still no luck